# jQuery 1.4.1 and Firefox 16.0.1 strange attribute issue

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-1.4, firefox-16

I recently came across a very very strange, and very bad bug in jQuery 1.4.1 when it comes to Firefox 16.0.1.  Every other browser is fine.  and older versions of Firefox are fine, and newer versions of jQuery are fine.

I have a table with some check boxes that look something like this:

```
<table class="EntityTable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="IdCheckBox" id="Checkfor654100" name="Checkfor654100" itemId="654100" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="IdCheckBox" id="Checkfor654101" name="Checkfor654101" itemId="654101" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="IdCheckBox" id="Checkfor654102" name="Checkfor654102" itemId="654102" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="IdCheckBox" id="Checkfor654103" name="Checkfor654103" itemId="654103" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and in javascript/jquery i loop through and collect all the itemIds

```
    var ids = new Array();

    $('input.IdCheckBox:checked').each(function(){
       var thisBox = $(this);
       ids.push(thisBox.attr('itemId'));

    });
```

In firefox 16.0.1, ids is populated with the url of the page. /theId  like: http://blahblahblah.com/654101

I was able to work around this by just changing it to:

```
ids.push(thisBox.attr('itemid'));
```

but, I'd like to know why this happened, and if anything else is affected by this.

Here is a JS Fiddle showing the problem in all it's glory:
http://jsfiddle.net/K8jRf/8/

Thanks!

Comment: Solution: don't use an old version of jQuery....

Comment: i have a solution, i posted it.  It's not always as easy as "don't use an old version"  I maintain an app that has probably 5000+ lines of javascript/jquery. and there are far to many breaking changes to just update to a new version of jquery on a whim.

Comment: A newer version most probably will **not** break your code unless there is something inherently wrong with it.

Comment: it will, the whole .attr vs .prop thing, and there was some changes with how ajax works.

Comment: The attr vs prop thing was fixed for the most part in `1.6.1`. ajax on the front end still works the same for the most part. only things that mainly changed are the backend code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does NOT seem to be a jQuery issue/bug but a FF16 (and FF17b) javascript issue/bug.
The following html-snippet shows the special behavior of itemId on (at least) li-elements:

```
<html><body><ul><li id="li1"></li></ul><script>
var element = document.getElementById("li1");
// assign to bla
element.bla = "hello";
// after
alert( element.bla ); // ok -> hello
// assign
element.itemId = "hello";
// after
alert( element.itemId ); // nok -> <file uri>hello
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Looks like "itemId" has become a "special attribute/behavior" as of FF16. typeof(element.itemId) is "string", even before assignment ...
FF15 behaves as expected.

Comment: very interesting.   i wonder why it worked on in my fiddle when i changed the version of jQuery to a more recent one!

Comment: looks like it's feature not a bug ... ;-) see bugzilla

Comment: yea, i've been watching that bug... pretty interestings "feature"

Comment: looks like it's part of HTML5 spec
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#attr-itemid

Answer (score 2):

Firefox "normalizes" attribute names to be all lowercase.

If you were using `data` instread of using `attr` you can do:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="IdCheckBox"
                id="Checkfor654101" name="Checkfor654101" data-itemId="654101" />
```

Js:

```
var itemId = $("input").data("itemId");
```

Comment: interesting, is there something special with itemId as an attribute or string?  Because other attributes i have, that are camel cased, are fine!

Comment: @Patricia weird, I am not sure.